# mkdtemp variant that returns a file descriptor?

Tags: security, unix, directory, posix, mkdir

Is there a `mkdtemp()` variant that returns the file descriptor of the created temporary directory?

I mean, something like `mkstemp()`, just for directories.

A file descriptor of a unique temporary directory would be useful in combination with functions like `openat()` (i.e. with functions that work relatively against a `dirfd`).

Answer (score 0):

I found none - no guarantee of non-existence of course.

Just a function that called `mkdtemp` and opened a directory pointer on it is one part.  But unless you can cleanup automatically, it becomes less useful.

You could put together a function which used `atexit` to cleanup. That effectively limits it to a predefined number of directories, since `atexit` accepts no parameters (one could have multiple functions for passing to `atexit` though).